# Where are these Outlook signatures stored?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I have two choices in the "Signatures" button, but when I go to edit them, they are not there! Where else does Outlook keep email rignatures; how can I edit or delete these?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try:   Signatures. You can find the various files that make up your Outlook signatures in one of the following locations: Windows 10 drive:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures. Older versions of Windows drive:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures.    ........  Otherwise I am not sure what has happened

Comment: @John that's it exactly! Thank you! Put it as an answer and I will accept it :-)

Comment: Done - I have posted an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see:

[Outlook Signatures](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-and-transfer-outlook-data-files-from-one-computer-to-another-0996ece3-57c6-49bc-977b-0d1892e2aacc#:%7E:text=Microsoft%5COutlook%5COutlprnt-,Signatures,%5CApplication%20Data%5CMicrosoft%5CSignatures)

You can find the various files that make up your Outlook signatures in one of the following locations:

Windows 10 drive:

\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures

Older versions of Windows drive:

\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures

Answer (score 0):

Outlook has changed itself. If you select E-mail account at the top, you will see a new 'Signatures on this device' where you will be able to change and edit.

Currently the only solution I have found is to add your Outlook Account name (same name as dropdown list) in brackets with the file name such as;
FileA (accountname).htm when editing the file in the AppData directory

this also lets you select it as the automatic file for new emails, and/or Forwards&Replies